# Channels using sockjs (node.js, socket.io)

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, sockjs

It came to my attention that `socket.io` has a lot of issues(memory leaks, CPU usage etc), therefore I am converting my application to `sockjs`(or something else..if this turns to be difficult to implement).

In `socket.io` I was able to easily emmit messages on several "cahnnels" using the same connection

```
socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
socket.emit('other', { hello: 'world' });
```

How can I achieve this using `sockjs`? I understand that this functionallyt has not been implemented in `sockjs`, but is there a reliable framework that does this? 
I run into this [websocket-multiplex](https://github.com/sockjs/websocket-multiplex) but wasn't satisfied with the reviews that I read on several blogs.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

I really like the direction the team over at the [primus](https://github.com/primus/primus) library is taking because there is so much churn in socket implementations right now. They allow you to freely switch between several of the most popular websocket libraries (including sockJS) with no additional code.

You could use primus with the community plugin [rooms](https://github.com/cayasso/primus-rooms) to accomplish what you are trying to do.

The plugin would allow you to do something like this:

```
spark.room('news').write( { hello : 'world' } );
```

A spark works almost the same way as a socket. Whenever primus receives a connection, it gives you a spark object to manipulate. So, here's a complete example:

```
var Primus = require('primus')
  , http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(/* request handler */)
  , primus = new Primus(server, { transformer: 'sockjs' });

primus.on('connection', function (spark) {
  spark.room('news').write( { hello : 'world' } );
});
```

Please note that there are a few [caveats](https://github.com/primus/primus#transformer-inconsistencies) to using sockJS with primus. The caveats won't affect your situation as you have described it.

Personally, I've had success with the good old [ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws) library combined with primus to get these nice features. It gives you RFC 6455 compliant sockets which helps when trying to connect to clients on multiple platforms.

**Update 0** 
*that is in response to a question in the comments about filtering rooms on client-side, follows:*

**First**, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/primus/primus#client-library) for client-side usage of primus, you'll need to access the primus client-side API. For development usage, a route is automatically added to your http server such that you can do the following in your html:

```
// use this to load the client-side framework in development only
<script src="/primus/primus.js"></script>
```

*Then*, take a look at the linked [documentation](https://github.com/primus/primus#client-library) for what you need to do in production to support the case where you need access to the primus library on the client.

**Second**, poke around in the primus-rooms client / server [examples](https://github.com/cayasso/primus-rooms#on-the-client) to see how to set things up. You can use [this](https://github.com/cayasso/primus-rooms#primusroomspark-name-fn) method to broadcast a message to a specific room.

Comment: Thank you! How would I filter different rooms on client side? I need to be able to listen and distinguish between messages coming from different rooms?

Answer (score 3):

Our team came up against very similar design concerns and the other day we just finished version 0 of a library that should help you. The documentation could use a bit of work but the tests pass so it should be in a state for you to mess around with if you'd like. We chose to implement publish-subscribe functionality instead of events since our stuff generally runs in a horizontally scaling environment and events would have to be implemented on top of publish-subscribe anyways. The library sits on top of express, redis and sockjs and provides easy token authentication logic, an RPC api surface, and publish-subscribe through redis.

Feel free to submit any issue tickets or feature requests, we're very open to changing it. It's a shame socket.io isn't supported because the community support on extensions such as multiplexing are really handy. Hopefully this helps remove some of the barriers to getting sockjs up and running quickly.

https://github.com/azuqua/node-token-sockjs

https://github.com/azuqua/jquery-token-sockjs

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look and let you know